# How to implement standard C function extraction?

Tags: c, function, standards

I have a "a pain in the a$$" task to extract/parse all standard C functions that were called in the main() function. Ex: printf, fseek, etc...

Currently, my only plan is to read each line inside the main() and search if a standard C functions exists by checking the list of standard C functions that I will also be defining (#define CFUNCTIONS "printf...")

As you know there are so many standard C functions, so defining all of them will be so annoying.

Any idea on how can I check if a string is a standard C functions?

Comment: Do you need only the standard functions that are *directly* called from `main`, or also those called indirectly (which would be all the standard functions in the program, assuming no dead code)?

Comment: Only directly called standard C functions

Comment: What is your definition of "standard" C function?

Answer (score 1):

If you have heard of cscope, try looking into the database it generates.  There are instructions available at the cscope front end to list out all the functions that a given function has called.

If you look at the list of the calls from main(), you should be able to narrow down your work considerably.

If you have to parse by hand, I suggest starting with the included standard headers.  They should give you a decent idea about which functions could you expect to see in main().

Either way, the work sounds non-trivial and interesting.

Comment: That's a great idea -- I think the way to go is definitely to leverage existing tools.  On Unix-based systems, I'd consider compiling to an object file, then using the `nm` utility to get a list of global symbols referenced in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing C source code seems simple at first blush, but as others have pointed out, the possibility of a programmer getting far off the leash by using `#define`s and `#include`s is rather common.  Unless it is known that the specific program to be parsed is mild-mannered with respect to text substitution, the complexity of parsing arbitrary C source code is considerable.

Consider the less used, but far more effective tactic of parsing the object module.  Compile the source module, but do not link it.  To further simplify, reprocess the file containing main to remove all other functions, but leave declarations in their places.

Depending on the requirements, there are two ways to complete the task:

1. Write a program which opens the object module and iterates through the external reference symbol table.  If the symbol matches one of the interesting function names, list it.  Many platforms have library functions for parsing an object module.
2. Write a command file or script which uses the developer tools to examine object modules.  For example, on Linux, the command `nm` lists external references with a `U`.

Answer (score 0):

The task may look simple at first but in order to be really 100% sure you would need to parse the C-file. It is not sufficient to just look for the name, you need to know the context as well i.e. when to check the id, first when you have determined that the id is a function you can check if it is a standard c-runtime function.

(plus I guess it makes the task more interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way around having to define a list of standard C functions to accomplish your task.  But it's even more annoying than that -- consider macros,
for example:

```
#define OUTPUT(foo) printf("%s\n",foo)

main()
{
   OUTPUT("Ha ha!\n");
}
```

So you'll probably want to run your code through the preprocessor before checking
which functions are called from main().  Then you might have cases like this:

```
some_func("This might look like a call to fclose(fp), but surprise!\n");
```

So you'll probably need a full-blown parser to do this rigorously, since string literals
may span multiple lines.

I won't bring up trigraphs...that would just be pointless sadism. :-) Anyway, good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: You might be able to derive the list of "standard" functions by parsing the relevant system header files for function definitions. Not trivial, but as long as you're writing a full-blown trigraph-savvy parser, what the heck!